# WPF Databinding ListView to a Property of an object which can be nothing

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I'm trying to create a Window with a ListView and an Area where details to the selected Object are displayed. The Listview displays items stored in an `ObservableCollection(Of T)` Collection. The items itself contain also an `ObservableCollecton(Of T)` Collection which should then be displayed in the details area in another ListView, accordingly to the selected item of the first `ListView`.

The Problem:
The InitializeComponent() throws an Exception (`XAMLParseException`).

Exception:
`Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding' threw an exception.`

InnerException:
`Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingBase'.`

The Line- and ColumNumer of the Exception are Pointing at the `<GridView>` of my ListView (.View)

This is the First ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectCollection, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Name" />
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And this is the second ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MySubCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView> <!-- Thats the Line where the Exception is pointing at -->
         <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="Key">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Key" />
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="Value">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Value" />
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

So. How can I bind to the Collection Property of an Object could be nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the exception message the problem is with with your `DisplayMemberBinding` in the second listview. Because you have to provide a Binding expression instead of a string [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx). Like in your first listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.MySubCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView> <!-- Thats the Line where the Exception is pointing at -->
         <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Key" />
         </GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Value" />
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a alot :). Just missed the Binding Expression. But I thought I've used it already without the Binding Expression... Maybe messed it up with something.. Anyway.. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think you messed it up with the `ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath` property, which is indeed a string.